# Finding all possible walks without repetition in an n*m grid

Tags: python, algorithm

I would like to find all the possible walks through a grid with dimension `n*m` where walks mustn't use a node more than once and are allowed to move to adjacent nodes (including diagonals).

For example, the `1*1` grid is trivial; there is only 1 possible walk, namely `[(0,0)]`. The `1*2` grid has 4 possible walks, namely `[(0,0)]`, `[(0,1)]`, `[(0,0),(0,1)]` and `[(0,1),(0,0)]`. The `2*2` grid has 4 trivial walks of length 1, those being `[(0,0)]`, `[(0,1)]`, `[(1,0)]` and `[(1,1)]`, 12 walks of length 2 `[(0,0), (0,1)]`, `[(0,0),(1,0)]`, `[(0,0),(1,1)]` and so on, 16 walks of length 3 (`[(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)]` etc.) and 16 walks of length 4 (`[(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]` etc.).

This is my attempt at implementing a recursive algorithm in python to list all possible walks in a n*m grid, but it doesn't return correct solutions. I approached it by iterating over all starting points, then forming a recursive tree of possible next steps.

```
dim=(2,2)

walks=[]

def main():
    for row in range(dim[0]):
        for col in range(dim[1]):
            walked=[[0 for i in range(dim[0])] for j in range(dim[1])]
            walkTree(row, col, walked, [])
    print(walks)

def walkTree(row, col, walked, leading):
    walks.append( leading+[(row,col)] )
    walked[row][col]=1
    leading.append((row,col))

    if row-1 >= 0:
        if col-1 >= 0:
            if not walked[row-1][col-1]:
                walkTree(row-1, col-1, walked, leading)
        if not walked[row-1][col]:
                walkTree(row-1, col, walked, leading)
        if col+1 < dim[1]:
            if not walked[row-1][col+1]:
                walkTree(row-1, col+1, walked, leading)

    if col-1 >= 0:
        if not walked[row][col-1]:
            walkTree(row, col-1, walked, leading)
    if col+1 < dim[1]:
        if not walked[row][col+1]:
            walkTree(row, col+1, walked, leading)

    if row+1 < dim[0]:
        if col-1 >= 0:
            if not walked[row+1][col-1]:
                walkTree(row+1, col-1, walked, leading)
        if not walked[row+1][col]:
                walkTree(row+1, col, walked, leading)
        if col+1 < dim[1]:
            if not walked[row+1][col+1]:
                walkTree(row+1, col+1, walked, leading)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Any help on why my code doesn't work or perhaps a better way to approach this problem is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you say you're also interested in "better ways" does that include external packages?

Comment: Sure, as long as it results in a way to iterate over all possible walks.

Comment: You haven't shown us the incorrect output, nor have you provided any execution trace.  What have you done to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) this, and what did you learn from that?

Comment: I tried your code on the (2,1) and (1,2) grids.  It faults with index out of range in both cases.

Comment: If this were my problem I would be using [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) and searching for a [self-avoiding walk](http://oeis.org/wiki/Index_to_OEIS:_Section_Wa). I would do this for you but need at least the first four numbers of the sequence.

Comment: Of interest: [Self-avoiding walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also another approach. You can reduce your problem to a known problem on graphs and then use a graph library to solve it.

1. Define you cells as nodes, connect all neighboring cells (including diagonals) with edges.
2. Add two additional nodes, s and d. Connect s to all your initial nodes, do the same for d.
3. Your question then becomes: find all simple paths between s and d. networkx library for python can do it (see https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html), so can igraph for R (and it will do it faster). For some strange reason there does not seem to be a similar function in igraph for python.

Comment: As a mathematics undergrad who's about graduate and has taken a course on graph theory, I'm a little ashamed I didn't see this graph theoretic approach myself; especially given that I've seen similar techniques employed for the stable marriage problem etc. This is far more elegant approach than mine, imo - thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Just as an update: I've successfully implemented this solution and it works as intended; although I've found it too inefficient for my application with a 4x4 grid (a "Boggle solver" in case you're curious) as the 4x4 Kings graph has 12 million simple paths (so the algorithm gets "stuck" down hopeless paths that contain no words). However this approach has led to better ideas on how I might solve (somewhat heuristically instead of exhaustively) my problem more efficiently. Namely searching for Hamiltonian paths first (since longer words are better) with various vertices removed. Thanks again!

Comment: @user406579, you're welcome; good to hear that you're having fun :)

Answer (score 0):

I added some tracing instrumentation. Output starting from (0,0) is below that.  The print statements are indented according to level, and I just print out the current location in a few useful spots.

Code:

```
dim=(2,2)
walks=[]
indent = ""

def main():
    for row in range(dim[0]):
        for col in range(dim[1]):
            walked=[[False for i in range(dim[0])] for j in range(dim[1])]
            walkTree(row, col, walked, [])

    for dist in range(1, dim[0]*dim[1]+1):
        print "length", dist, "\n\t", [path for path in walks if len(path) == dist]

def walkTree(row, col, walked, leading):
    global indent
    print indent, "ENTER", "pos", row, col, "walked=", walked, "lead=", leading
    indent += "  "
    walks.append( leading+[(row,col)] )
    walked[row][col] = True
    leading.append((row,col))

    print indent, "ROW-", row, col, walked
    if row-1 >= 0:
        if col-1 >= 0:
            if not walked[row-1][col-1]:
                walkTree(row-1, col-1, walked, leading)
        if not walked[row-1][col]:
                walkTree(row-1, col, walked, leading)
        if col+1 < dim[1]:
            if not walked[row-1][col+1]:
                walkTree(row-1, col+1, walked, leading)

    print indent, "COL-", row, col, walked
    if col-1 >= 0:
        if not walked[row][col-1]:
            walkTree(row, col-1, walked, leading)

    print indent, "COL+", row, col, walked
    if col+1 < dim[1]:
        if not walked[row][col+1]:
            walkTree(row, col+1, walked, leading)

    print indent, "ROW+", row, col, walked
    if row+1 < dim[0]:
        if col-1 >= 0:
            if not walked[row+1][col-1]:
                walkTree(row+1, col-1, walked, leading)
        if not walked[row+1][col]:
                walkTree(row+1, col, walked, leading)
        if col+1 < dim[1]:
            if not walked[row+1][col+1]:
                walkTree(row+1, col+1, walked, leading)

    indent = indent[2:]
```

In the output (I printed only the first 1/4), note how you cover only one linear path from the (0,0) starting point: you step to (0,1), then (1,0), and finally (1,1).  However, when you return from each of those steps, you fail to cover any other options, such as moving (0,0) => (0,1) => (1,1) and from there to (1,0).

The fatal flaw is that you don't manage your status lists when you backtrack.  In the case shown below, when you backtrack even to (0,0), you still have the entire grid marked as *walked*.  Instead, try either reset code: just before you return from the routine,

```
walked[row,col] = False
```

... or make a local copy of `walked`, rather than dealing with a what is essentially a global master list.

I'll leave the handling of `leading` up to you, now that you have the hint.

Output:

```
 ENTER pos 0 0 walked= [[False, False], [False, False]] lead= []
   ROW- 0 0 [[True, False], [False, False]]
   COL- 0 0 [[True, False], [False, False]]
   COL+ 0 0 [[True, False], [False, False]]
   ENTER pos 0 1 walked= [[True, False], [False, False]] lead= [(0, 0)]
     ROW- 0 1 [[True, True], [False, False]]
     COL- 0 1 [[True, True], [False, False]]
     COL+ 0 1 [[True, True], [False, False]]
     ROW+ 0 1 [[True, True], [False, False]]
     ENTER pos 1 0 walked= [[True, True], [False, False]] lead= [(0, 0), (0, 1)]
       ROW- 1 0 [[True, True], [True, False]]
       COL- 1 0 [[True, True], [True, False]]
       COL+ 1 0 [[True, True], [True, False]]
       ENTER pos 1 1 walked= [[True, True], [True, False]] lead= [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)]
         ROW- 1 1 [[True, True], [True, True]]
         COL- 1 1 [[True, True], [True, True]]
         COL+ 1 1 [[True, True], [True, True]]
         ROW+ 1 1 [[True, True], [True, True]]
       ROW+ 1 0 [[True, True], [True, True]]
   ROW+ 0 0 [[True, True], [True, True]]
 ENTER pos 0 1 walked= [[False, False], [False, False]] lead= []
   ROW- 0 1 [[False, True], [False, False]]
   COL- 0 1 [[False, True], [False, False]]
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see what the problem is, but I don't know what's causing it. I've tried creating a local copy of walked as you suggest but it doesn't appear to make an difference. Moreover, I don't understand why other iterations of the function get passed previous iteration's walked - I meant for each to run with their own walked list that its passed when called. I don't see why creating a local copy doesn't fix this issue.

Comment: Your posted code hasn't created a local copy of `walked`: you created one in the main program and passed it to every iteration.  Did you check your functionality with a few print statements?